# How to find a column value anywhere in another data frame and return the column name

Tags: r

As the questions states, I am trying to find a column value(in A$X[i]) anywhere in another data frame(in B) and return the column name(B$[j]).

I have two tables here:

```
Client Account df
JOHN     KATE    RAM    ABE
2341    K919    Q1234   23445
V454    56783   88872   9009
87874   345GH   63547   8834S
```

```
Client details df
Date        ClientNumber   Region   Amount      Insurance 
12/5/2015   9009           EMEA     15236.23    Yes
12/5/2015   K919           EMEA     1889.22     No
12/5/2015   87874          EMEA     152000.0    No
12/5/2015   345GH          EMEA     28877.53    Yes
12/5/2015   9009           EMEA     90000.89    Yes
```

I am trying to add Client name to Client details table
Desired output:

```
Client details table
Date        ClientNumber   Region   Amount      Insurance  Name
12/5/2015   9009           EMEA     15236.23    Yes        ABE
12/5/2015   K919           EMEA     1889.22     No         KATE
12/5/2015   87874          EMEA     152000.0    No         JOHN
12/5/2015   345GH          EMEA     28877.53    Yes        KATE
12/5/2015   9009           EMEA     90000.89    Yes        ABE
```

The tables are so big that I would love to make use of vectorization than using a loop.

Comment: If you convert that first frame to long, with a name column a client_number column and two other character columns for the last two rows, then you can just merge on ClientNumber and client_number. That would be easiest

Comment: Perfect, Thanks brother!

Comment: Sister...but your welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the first data frame is `A` and the second is `B`.  You should be able to merge the two using the packages `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

A %>% 
  gather(JOHN:ABE, key = Name, Value = ClientNumber) %>% 
  left_join(B, ., by = "ClientNumber")
```

The `left_join` uses the full dataset `B` and merges with the newly modified dataset `A` by `ClientNumber`

Comment: Thanks for the save.  Not sure where my head is...meant `gather`, not `df`...time for another cup of coffee I suppose

Answer (score 0):

it would have been better if you pasted the results of maybe `dput(head(data))` here for one to be able to easily answer. Since no loops neither the classes that contain loop in the background such as `*apply` functions needed, then I guess you will need to do things in a vector format:

```
 Details$Name <- names(unlist(AccountDF))[match(Details$clientnumber,unlist(AccountDF),nomatch = 0)]
```

I hope it might help

Comment: Thanks much! cant buy the bread if i don't use dummy data. sorry.

Comment: Well,  the thing is the codes here are for free..  No one sells them.  And it is just reasonably okay to just give a small subset of your data for you to be answered in a well ordered and detailed manner. Thanks